# can't make http request to docker container?

Tags: api, docker, post, networking, dockerfile

I am having an issue where my docker container, a simple api, is reachable from the browser if I open `localhost:5000` it works fine and I get my dummy test, that means it's online, but when I go to postman to test my post request I get

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:5000/test
```

I already tried disabling proxy settings and SSl certificates in postman and in my dockerfile my flask runs with the `0.0.0.0` host setting and the 5000 port is being exposed in the same dockerfile, I already ran out of ideas of why I can make or at least get responses from the docker container when it works just fine in the browser.

Edit.

the docker file is

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc
RUN apk add alpine-sdk
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN apk update  && apk add  curl make gnupg  gcc g++ unixodbc-dev
RUN pip install -r ./src/requirements.txt
RUN pip install pyodbc==4.0.27
ENV FLASK_APP=./src/app.py
EXPOSE 5000
CMD flask run --host 0.0.0.0
```

the start command is `docker run -p 5000:5000 -t -d ms`

the result of all that is

`01bfd6b0bc6b  ms   "/bin/sh -c 'flask r…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   elastic_lovelace`

Comment: Please post your docker file, what did you do to start the container, the curl response and other stuff. It's hard to comment without any clue of what's going on and what have been done.

Comment: I just updated the post